# how to command line VLC to RTSP IPCAM

Tags: vlc

I wish to use VLC to stream IPCAM(s) to UBUNTU.
I found a way doing it using VLC:
Stream Media as : `rtsp://192.168.3.101:554`, and I choose "8000ms" of cache, and take 1:4 zoom.

How can it be done using a command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part a bash script:

```
cvlc -vvv --network-caching $cache rtsp://192.168.3.$port:554 --zoom $zoom
```

While `$cache` is buffer size in ms.
And `$port` define cam's port